# Data from controller to service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which looks like this:

```
    class DemandCtrl {
        constructor(ChartDataService) {
            this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;

            this.dataa = {
                from: 'test1',
                to: 'test2'
            };
        }

        $onInit() {
            getData.call(null, this);       
        }

    }

function getData(DemandCtrl) {
    DemandCtrl.ChartDataService.getData().then(result => {
        DemandCtrl.result = result.data;
        getChart(result.data);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

...other methods...

DemandCtrl.$inject = ['ChartDataService'];

export const Demand = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: demandPageHtml,
    controller: DemandCtrl
};
```

And a service where I want to get the content of `dataa.from` and `dataa.to` to be the parameters of a method in the service.

This is how the service look and what I've tried:

```
export default class ChartDataService {
    constructor($http, authService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    getData(dataa.from, dataa.to) {

        return this.$http.get(`${RTM_API_URL}chartData?interval=FIFTEEN_MINUTES&fromDate=` + dataa.from + `&toDate=`+ dataa.to, config)
            .then(result => {
            return result;
        }).catch(() => {
            return Promise.reject('Failed to access chart data ');
        });
    }
}

ChartDataService.$inject = ['$http', 'authService'];
```

It says that `dataa` is undefined. Any ideas what's the good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the stand -alone function getData(). Just put that code inside $onInit using this.ChartdataService and pass this.dataa to the call to it's getData.

```
 class DemandCtrl {
        constructor(ChartDataService) {
            this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;

            this.dataa = {
                from: 'test1',
                to: 'test2'
            };
        }

        $onInit() {
            this.ChartDataService.getData(this.dataa.from, this.dataa.to).then(result => {
                this.result = result.data;
                getChart(result.data);
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            })
        }

    }

DemandCtrl.$inject = ['ChartDataService'];

export const Demand = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: demandPageHtml,
    controller: DemandCtrl
};

export default class ChartDataService {
    constructor($http, authService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    getData(dataa.from, dataa.to) {

        return this.$http.get(`${RTM_API_URL}chartData?interval=FIFTEEN_MINUTES&fromDate=` + dataa.from + `&toDate=`+ dataa.to, config)
            .then(result => {
            return result;
        }).catch(() => {
            return Promise.reject('Failed to access chart data ');
        });
    }
}

ChartDataService.$inject = ['$http', 'authService'];
```